# My list elements are forming a stair case

Tags: css, asp.net

I want to have a title before my ul tags but this causes a staircase on my browsers.

I have read about the staircase bug in internet explore here https://www.sanwebe.com/2015/03/15-common-css-bugs-and-their-easy-fixes however i am using chrome.

Here is my html code:

```
     <asp:Label CssClass="listHeading" ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"> 
     </asp:Label>
     <section>
  <ul class="tasks">
       <li class="elem">
        </li>
         <li class="elem"></li>
         <li class="elem"></li>
       </ul>
     </section>
     <asp:Label CssClass="listHeading" ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<section>
  <ul class="tasks">
  </ul>
</section>
     <asp:Label CssClass="listHeading" ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<section>
  <ul class="tasks">
  </ul>
</section>

and here is my css code:

    .listHeading {
         font-weight: normal;
         float:none;
         text-align:unset;
         margin-left:4%;
    }
    .tasks{
         float:left;
         margin-top:40px;
         background-color:#ccf;
         margin:0 5px;
         padding:10px;
         width:14%;
         min-height:60px; 
         border:1px solid #669;
     }
    .elem{
         list-style-type:none;
         margin-bottom:5px;
         padding:0 10px;
         background-color:#fff;
         border:1px solid #99c;
         font-size:100%;
         height:100%;
         line-height:48px; 
        width:90%;
     }
     .on_tasks{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        height:100%;
        width:50%;
        background-color:#eef;
        margin-top:40%;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a

```
clear: left;
```

to your `.listHeading` class. This will, however, not work for any content after the last `<ul class="tasks>`. Instead, you could look for the typical "clearfix" styles and apply them to your `<section>`s.

Clearfix looks like this:

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Then, just apply `class="clearfix"` to your `<section>` tags, and you should be safe. Whenever you want to float something, you should "clearfix" the container, to get the expected results.

That said, why are you floating your `<ul>`s in the first place?

**UPDATE 1 (float / use flex layout / use table)**

Ok, if you want to make a Kanban layout, you should float your headings together with your lists, not just the list itself.

```
<div class="kanban-column">
  <label>Col 1</label>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="kanban-column">
  <label>Col 2</label>
  <ul>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then just apply `float: left` to `.kanban-column` and nowhere else.

BUT: I would strongly advise you to either use a flex layout or a table for your purposes. You will most likely get into serious trouble with your floated items, when your screen gets too small.

I know, many people say "tables are soooo old school". But, tables aren't evil per se. Tables should be used for exactly that purpose: as a table. And your Kanban board basically *is* a table. It has columns, it has two rows, one with headers and one with data. Why not treat it as such. Plus, it will make your life much easier during implementation.

Comment: I am floating the ul left because I want to make a kanban  https://www.google.com/search?q=kanban&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixpMXTxL7gAhULpFkKHc2ECucQ_AUIDigB